# angularJS editable text area click to leave

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this editable text field directive in angular which looks like this

```
myApp.directive('editable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            placeholder: '@'
        },
        replace: false,
        template: '<span>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Press enter to submit changes" ng-model="model" style="width: 100%; font-size: 18px" ng-show="edit" ng-enter="edit=false"></input>' +
        '<span ng-show="!edit">{{model || placeholder}} <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:14px;"></i></span>' +
        '</span>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.edit = false;
            element.bind('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(scope.edit = true);
                element.find('input').focus();
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.charCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 13) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.ngEnter);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

As you can see its currently using an `ng-enter`, Which is applying the on the enter key.

I'm wanting it so that when you click off the element, It does the same as the enter key does.

i tried adding this which hadn't worked.

```
myApp.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.charCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 13) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.ngEnter);
            }
        });
        element.bind('keypress', function (m) {
            if (m.charCode === 1 || m.keyCode === 1) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.ngEnter);
            }
          });
    };
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this doesnt work

Comment: can you please create a plunker?

Comment: i tired adding it to a plunker but i couldnt get the edit to work! however its working fine in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `blur` event. Replace the second `keypress` bind to something like this:

```
element.bind('blur', function (e) {
    scope.$apply(attrs.ngEnter);
});
```

Comment: Sorry worked this out, Would can also do the simpler method `ng-blur`